# Is there a way to keep super relative to the subclass?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, prototypal-inheritance

If I define two classes as follows...

```
class A {
  getParentInstance(...args) {
    return new super.constructor(...args);
  }
}

class B extends A {}

console.log((new B).getParentInstance().constructor.name);
```

`Object` is logged to the console, instead of my desired `A`. This is due to the `super` in `A.prototype.getParentInstance` referencing the superclass of `A` specifically which is `Object`. This is opposed to the alternative, which would be `super` being relative to the current level in the prototype chain -- for `B` that would be `A`.

My question is: Is there a way to define methods in such a way to use the **relative** super at each level of the prototype chain when inherited? Effectively resulting in...

```
(new B).getParentInstance().constructor.name === 'A'
```

Comment: a factory method like that would usually be static...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little `Object.getPrototypeOf()` magic seems to be the trick:

```
class A {
  getParentInstance(...args) {
    const thisProto = this.constructor.prototype;
    const RelativeSuperConstructor = Object.getPrototypeOf(thisProto).constructor;
    return new RelativeSuperConstructor(...args);
  }
}

class B extends A {}

console.log((new B).getParentInstance().constructor.name);
```

results in the correct "super" being grabbed, and thus logs `'A'` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
class A {
  static getParentConstructor() {
    return Object;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  static getParentConstructor() {
    return A;
  }
}

var b = new B();
var a = new (b.constructor.getParentConstructor())();
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a good solution -- I was hoping though to not have the redundant code by using inheritance if possible.

Comment: figured out a way to do it above.